# Textbox not clears when clicks the submit button

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to clear the `txtSubTotal` text box after clicking the `PROCEED` button. It's not working though I tried some code examples, even in SO.

**btnProceed/HTML**

```
<input type="submit" name="btnProceed" id="btnProceed" value="PROCEED" onclick="clearSubTotal();"/>
```

**clearSubTotal()/JS**

```
function clearSubTotal() {
$('#txtSubTotal').val('');
}
```

**txtSubTotal**

```
<input name="txtSubTotal" type="text" id="txtSubTotal" size="15" value="<?php 
$sql=mysqli_query($connection,"select sum(amount) from sales_temp");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
echo $row[0];
?>"/>
```

**form/HTML**

```
 <form id="manageSalesForm" name="manageSalesForm" method="post" action="<?php echo BASE_URL?>includes/functions/sales_functions.php">
```

[image]

Appreciate your help on this.

NOTE: Found that on the second button press, the text box clears. How to set this correctly for the first button perss?

**ADD button/JS**

```
     function submitdata() {
     var listItemName  = document.getElementById("listItemName").value;
     var listStock = document.getElementById("listStock").value;
     var txtUnitPrice = document.getElementById("txtUnitPrice").value;
     var txtQuantity = document.getElementById("txtQuantity").value;
     var listCustomer = document.getElementById("listCustomer").value;
     var txtReceiptNo = document.getElementById("txtReceiptNo").value;
     var TheDate = document.getElementById("TheDate").value;

     // Returns successful data submission message when the entered information is stored in database.
     var dataString = {listItemName:listItemName, listStock: listStock, txtUnitPrice: txtUnitPrice, txtQuantity: txtQuantity, listCustomer: listCustomer, txtReceiptNo: txtReceiptNo};
     if (listItemName == '' || listStock == ''|| txtUnitPrice == ''|| txtQuantity == ''|| listCustomer == ''|| txtReceiptNo == ''|| TheDate == '') {
     salesitemsAddFail();
     } 
     else {
                // AJAX code to submit form.
                $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/pms/includes/functions/sales_temp_functions.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(html) {    

     //reload the sales datagrid once add the item details to temporary table (sales_temp)
     $('#list').trigger("reloadGrid",[{page:1}]);
         window.location.reload();
                }
                });
            }
}
$('#btnProceed').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // stops form submission
$('#txtSubTotal').val('');
});
```

**ADD button/HTML**

```
<td width="46"><button type="button" name="btnSave" id="btnSave" onclick="submitdata(); check_qty(); showSubTotal();">ADD</button></td>
```

**sales_functions.php**

```
<?php

//Start the Session
       if(!isset($_SESSION)) 
       { 
           session_start(); 
       } 

include ("/../../pages/sales.php");
include("/../../dbutil.php");

 if(isset($_POST['listCustomer'])){ $customer = $_POST['listCustomer'];}
 if(isset($_POST['staff'])){ $user = $_POST['staff']; }

if(isset($_POST['btnProceed'])){

$result=mysqli_query($connection, 
"INSERT INTO sales(cus_id,item_id,stock_id,receipt_no,qty,unit_price,amount,user_id,purchase_id) 
 SELECT C.cus_id, I.item_id, S.stock_id, $receipt_no, ST.qty, ST.unit_price, ST.amount, U.id, P.purchase_id 
FROM customers C, items I, stock S, sales_temp ST, users U, purchase_items P 
WHERE ST.staff='$user' 
AND C.customer_name='$customer' 
AND I.item_name=ST.item_name 
AND S.stock_code=ST.stock_code 
AND ST.purchase_id=P.purchase_id");


//Update available qty from purchase_items relevant only to the logged in user(sales_temp table may have records from multiple users)
$resultUpdate=mysqli_query($connection, "UPDATE purchase_items P INNER JOIN sales_temp ST ON (P.purchase_id = ST.purchase_id) SET P.avail_qty = (P.avail_qty - ST.qty) WHERE ST.staff='$user'");

//Delete records relevant only to current user. Here 'WHERE' clause use to prevent deleting other user's records.
$resultDelete=mysqli_query($connection, "DELETE FROM sales_temp WHERE staff='$user'");


if (!$result) {
  printf("Errormessage: %s\n", mysqli_error($connection));
}

// use exec() because no results are returned
if ($result) {

}
else
{
  echo '<script type="text/javascript">',
 'salesAddFail();',
'</script>';
}}
?>
```

Comment: What is your `form` element's `action` attribute set to? Most likely, after you submit, the same page is being reloaded and the default value from your .php is being re-established. If you set the form's `action` properly, you won't need to manually clear the field(s).

Comment: @ScottMarcus I added the HTML code for the `form`.

Comment: Your `<input>` has the attribute `value="<?php [...] echo $row[0]; ?>"`. So, whenever the page loads, that will be the value of the `<input>`.

Comment: @Rounin Do you have any idea, how to reset textbox after submitting the button, and get the textbox value after that, with the call of that event.

Comment: @EKBG If you are going to repopulate the form field, why bother clearing it out first?

Comment: @ScottMarcus I will add my scenario on the post.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I added the screenshot for further reference of my scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, added the `do_onload(id)` to calculate the total on `loadComplete` event which is triggered after each refresh (also after delete)

```
function do_onload(id)
{
//alert('Simulating, data on load event')

var s = $("#list").jqGrid('getCol', 'amount', false, 'sum');
jQuery("#txtSubTotal").val(s);
}
```

And changed the phpgrid code accordingly.

```
$opt["loadComplete"] = "function(ids) { do_onload(ids); }";
$grid->set_options($opt);
```

Answer (score 2):

After clicking on the submit button, the form is being submitted and your custom function is not being executed.

Delete the *onclick* from your input element and **edit your jQuery code**:

```
$('#btnProceed').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // stops form submission
  $('#txtSubTotal').val('');
});
```

You can try it in your browser: https://jsfiddle.net/hy7jwg8m/1/

Comment: I copied the code and run it on localhost and it works for me. Your code is submitting the form, so the key is really to add the event.preventDefault() method. Could you be more specific and maybe copy the whole code here or to jsfiddle, please?

Comment: Here is the version that works perfectly, try it yourself: https://jsfiddle.net/hy7jwg8m/1/ (PHP code doesn't run there, but it doesn't matter). I wrote comments for what I've changed. Let me know if it works.

Comment: No luck. Still having the same issue, though the fiddle works. Hope I have any incompatibility of the code.

Comment: And what exactly is it doing? Refreshing the page? Showing an error? Could you check your console output if there is any JS error, for instance?

Comment: Page refreshes, but the **Sub Total** not clears out. It clears when click the **Proceed** on the second time. No errors in console, my bad.

Comment: It seems like a cache problem. Try to clear the cache in the browser and try again (or try another browser). Make sure you're using the updated JS file. Sorry, I cannot think of another possible reason...

Answer (score 1):

It is working perfect for me. And after clicking on submit it might be working for you but with the same time page will be redirected to new action

Comment: On the second button press of the `PROCEED` button, it clears the text box. How to clear the text box on first click?

Comment: check by added console.log to debug.. It should be called at first click only

Comment: can you help me to solve this, by editing my code, as you suggested.

Comment: '<input name="txtSubTotal" type="text" id="txtSubTotal" size="15" value="asjlknhasdjkh"/>
 <form action="#">
 <input type="submit" name="btnProceed" id="btnProceed" value="PROCEED" onclick="clearSubTotal();"/>
 </form>
 
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function clearSubTotal() {
   $('#txtSubTotal').val('');  
   
  }
 </script>' **hope this will help you

Comment: in above code snippet you will be able to see the textbox is getting empty for very small time interval